# Python: no more mksalt?

Tags: python

On old distros I use this nice line to create a working password hash

```
python -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("MYPASSWORDTEXT", crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'
```

But now give me error.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mksalt'
```

Is there a substitute with the latest python3?

EDIT: My mistake...python is linked to python2 instead of python3!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine on my python 3.8

```
❯ python -V
Python 3.8.2

~
❯ python -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("MYPASSWORDTEXT", crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'
$6$CJ1ylbskoIFazaiG$nSY3cCgUeNudDWMIp3Z5/VILOqX1epJ0Mor07qzOWySMESES8T1NHfBMnSBtbvbDtOOf4KDLYUW5ECK2FN2MT/

~
❯
```

`crypt` is part of the Python Standard Library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html